# How to write regular expression for given text

Tags: jmeter, regex

I have below text content:

```
trusted/75XqScyKRbuRYEATFl2cWg==:IUMN4RxUoWGSFvJMTJ69TkaA/t
```

Where I've to extract only `75XqScyKRbuRYEATFl2cWg==:IUMN4RxUoWGSFvJMTJ69TkaA`
text. Someone please help me to write a RegEx for this.

Comment: prescribing regex as the solution makes this a classic XY problem.  This really looks like something you should be splitting on separators, not using regex for.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
^trusted\/(.*)\/t$
```

This will return a string between `trusted/` and `/t` if the original string starts from `trusted/` and finishes with `/t`. Otherwise use just `trusted\/(.*)\/t`.

Check the test here: https://regex101.com/r/ZeiORB/1

**UPD:**

As per OP's comment here is a fixed regexp addressing the input from comment:

```
trusted\\\/(.*)\\\/t
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/ZeiORB/2/

Comment: Sorry above one i have mentioned was wrong following is the whole response

Comment: I have the following whole response                                                                                                   {"options":{"hideTabs":true,"hideToolbar":true,"width":0,"height":0},"url":"https:\/\/staging-athena.wkelmsolutions.com\/trusted\/ndr4JPOlT7uDzHGnPYXe3g==:X6IDO7mkZqzht_pe-GRZ-hSd\/t\/C09322\/views\/Leanbook\/LeanViz"}                                         from above i have to extract ndr4JPOlT7uDzHGnPYXe3g==:X6IDO7mkZqzht_pe-GRZ-hSd

Comment: @RanganathaReddy Check update regarding your comment